# Logback configuration via jvm argument

Tags: java, logging, web-applications, logback

How can we load logback.xml via jvm argument if this is not present in project classpath?

I'm using

```
 -Dlogback.configuration=file:C:\logbacs\logback.xml
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I found the solution

```
-Dlogging.config="C:\logbacs\logback.xml"
```

is working fine for me.

*Updated because the previous answer was obsolete*

Comment: ...where do we specify the location of file, is it in VM arguments in RUN configuration of my eclipse project OR is it a configuration file in tomcat ?

Comment: its VM argument of project.

Answer (score 24):

If you're not using SpringBoot the above won't work.

I'm using the ch.qos.logback.logback-classic library, and in this case the solution is

```
-Dlogback.configurationFile=file:/app/logback.xml
```

I've found this property in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer:

```
final public static String CONFIG_FILE_PROPERTY = "logback.configurationFile"
```

Comment: This definitely not correct anymore in recent versions of spring boot. It's `-Dlogging.config`, see answer by @Fre_d

Comment: like I've said, I've used -Dlogback.configurationFile property because I wasn't using spring boot. If you use SB, then you should use -Dlogging.config

Comment: Not necessary to explore Logback's source code, using this property is explained here : http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#configFileProperty

Comment: For Windows -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:///C:/logbacs/logback.xml

Answer (score 5):

The original answer to this question doesn't appear to be working anymore as it produces this warning instead:

```
o.s.b.l.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem     : Ignoring 'logback.configurationFile' system property. Please use 'logging.config' instead.
```

Therefore, you would want to use something like this:

```
-Dlogging.config="C:\logbacs\logback.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it works only with this property:

```
-Dconfig.dir= "YOUR PATH TO CONFIG FILE"
```

Answer (score 0):

As per https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html, use **-Dlogback.configurationFile**

```
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml chapters.configuration.MyApp1
```